# A company manufactures two varieties of pens

Tags: word-problem, operations-research

> A company manufactures two varieties of pens: $A$ and $B$. Each pen $A$ needs $2$ hours of labor, whereas each pen $B$ needs $1$ hour of labor. Total labor hours available is $500$ hours per month. The demand for $A$ pens is $\rm{Rs.}150$ per month. The demand for $B$ pens is $\rm{Rs.}250$ per month. The profits that the two varieties fetch are $\rm{Rs.}8$ and $\rm{Rs.}5$ per pen. Formulate the linear program.

Can somebody tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Where's your work? What decision variables did you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved with any software or algorithm for (linear) integer optimization problems (since you don't want to manufacture fractions of pens). 
The free software R features some optimization packages for your type of problem such as the `lpSolve` package.
Commerical solvers like Cplex or Xpress will also easily solve your problem and find the optimal solution.